# How can i set a List to be not empty with Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-data

I have this property in my Entity

```
@Column(nullable = false)
private List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
```

I am trying to set locations to 'not empty' but I cant use Annotations like @Size(min = 1). Is there a Spring data equivalent to this? Im not able to find it.

Comment: Why would Spring data reinvent a different bean validator framework since JPA (and Spring in general) supports bean validation already. Why can't you use bean validation?

Comment: did u check `@NotEmpty`. You cannot use this?